# Bean define error: no getter method found for the property name

Tags: jsp, properties, struts-1

I am facing this weird error , where i have used the `bean:define` tag in jsp and the property name I have used is throwing an error.

```
No getter method for property: "flatRate3GDataPlansEnabled" of bean
```

Heres my getter and setters in the `Actionform`:

```
private boolean flatRate3GDataPlansEnabled=false;

public boolean isFlatRate3GDataPlansEnabled() {
    return flatRate3GDataPlansEnabled;
}

public void setFlatRate3GDataPlansEnabled(boolean aFlatRate3GDataPlansEnabled) {
    flatRate3GDataPlansEnabled = aFlatRate3GDataPlansEnabled;
}
```

Heres the jsp tag:

```
<bean:define id="flatRate3GDataPlansEnabled" name="FlatRateSmsActionForm"
    property="flatRate3GDataPlansEnabled" type="java.lang.Boolean" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Struts 1.x uses `get`/`set` methods to access bean properties. Rename your method to

```
public boolean getFlatRate3GDataPlansEnabled() {
    return flatRate3GDataPlansEnabled;
}
```